# How to use lazy loading in UIButton image?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uibutton

I use this logic for creating button in scroll view.
`int m=0;
        int j = [imageData count]/3;
        int s = [imageData count]%3;
        if(s==1 || s==2)
        {
            j=j+1;
        }
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,j*155);

```
    int i,k,x=0,y=0;
    for(i=0;i<j;i++)
    {
        if(s==0){
            for(k=0;k<3;k++)
            {
                button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];          
                [button setFrame:CGRectMake(13+x,10+y, 91,135)];
                int p;
                NSLog(@"%i",p++);
                [button setTag:m];
                [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
                NSData *imagesubCategoryData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[imageData objectAtIndex:m]]];
                [button setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imagesubCategoryData] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                [scrollView addSubview:button];
                x=x+101;
                m++;
            }
        }
        else if(s==1)
        {
            for(k=0;k<3;k++)
            {
                button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

                [button setFrame:CGRectMake(13+x,10+y, 91,135)];
                [button setTitle:@"Button"  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                int p;
                NSLog(@"%i",p++);
                [button setTag:m];
                [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
                NSData *imagesubCategoryData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[imageData objectAtIndex:m]]];
                [button setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imagesubCategoryData] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                [scrollView addSubview:button];
                x=x+101;
                if(i==j-1 && k==0)
                {
                    break;
                }
                m++;
            }
        }
        else if(s==2)
        {
            for(k=0;k<3;k++)
            {

                button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];;
                [button setFrame:CGRectMake(13+x,10+y, 91,135)];
                [button setTitle:@"Button"  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                int p;
                NSLog(@"%i",p++);
                [button setTag:m];
                [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
                NSData *imagesubCategoryData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[imageData objectAtIndex:m]]];
                [button setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imagesubCategoryData] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                [scrollView addSubview:button];
                x=x+101;
                if(i==j-1 && k==1)
                {
                    break;
                }
                m++;
            }
        }

        x=0;
        y=y+145;
    }
```

`

Comment: Try explaining what you want to achieve, "lazy loading button image" is not very clear.

Comment: In this method i create a button and set images on button.
All button create and images set then after scroll view show the data
i want to load images one by one on button

Comment: Hi Can,
i want to create many button in scroll view and then load images on that button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find Democode on lazy load at [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html)

Hope from this one u can got logic for Lazy loading...